# How to exclude expired users from AD sync?

Tags: connection, ad

I am using sp 2010. I would like to exclude expired users from the AD sync connection. How can I implement this?

NOTE
I mean Expired date and not Disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an LDAP filter in the synchronisation connection to exclude users based on the accountExpires attribute e.g.

```
(accountExpires>=127457662500870736)
```

You can generate the 64bit number using PowerShell. I generated the number in the example as follows:

```
 ((get-date).addyears(-10)).toFiletime()
```

Edit:

To add the filter edit your sync connection. Locate the user filter box and add the following filter:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(accountExpires>=127457662500870736))
```

You can verify this returns the results you want from AD first by selecting find and then custom search and pasting in the above query.

Comment: Dear Bunazb, thank you. How to do somethin like this?: (accountExpires >= currentDate)

Comment: See my edit for more details.