# Exclude expired accounts from the UPS import

Tags: 2013, ad, ups

I need to be able to exclude users from the import from AD that have an account that is expired BUT not disabled.

We currently filter like this

```
   Attribute            Operator    Filter                                                                                          
   userAccountControl   Bit on equals   2
```

So any account that is disabled is not imported.  But we have the situation where we need to exclude accounts that have expired that maybe enabled still.

Comment: This is for 2010 but I think it should still be valid for 2013. http://www.harbar.net/archive/2011/02/22/323.aspx

Comment: This only covers expired passwords not where an expiry date on the account is less than today

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the Passowrd expiray then their is filter for it.

- userAccountControl Bit on equals 24 OR
- userAccountControl Bit on equals 5 OR ( this is for the Locked account)

But another way is.

- Create another OU and move all expired account into that OU then exclude that from the Import.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d94663b7-09f2-4a57-9389-9dc1e834b501/exclude-expired-accounts-in-user-profile-synchronization?forum=sharepointadmin

Also check this one [How to exclude expired users from AD sync?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122091/how-to-exclude-expired-users-from-ad-sync)